# Promise.resolve - Unexpected result

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise

I don't understand Promises. I know that Promises are Objects that can finish successfully or erroneously. And promises are good to execute asynchronous functions and concatenate other asynchronous function via `then`. The result of a promise is passed as parameter to a callback function inside the `then` method of the last executed promise (if the promise ends right).

This example doesn't work. I am simulating an asynchronous call via setTimeout. My function returns an integer. I am expecting to get a 5 as result of `prom2`. Why doesn't work? What I am doing wrong and why?

```
var getProductId = function(){
    setTimeout(function () {
        return 5;
    }, 1500);
};
var prom2 = Promise.resolve(getProductId);

prom2.then(function(result){
    console.log("5 = " + result);
});
```

I tried also:

```
var getProductId = function(){
    setTimeout(function () {
        return 5;
    }, 1500);
};
var prom2 = Promise.resolve(getProductId());

prom2.then(function(result){
    console.log("5 = " + result);
});
```

Note: I want to use `Promise.resolve` and not `new Promise`.

Comment: `Promise.resolve` makes synchronous code behave async, it creates an immediately resolved promise with whatever value you give it. It cannot work with async code. Even though you don't want to, you should use `new Promise`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that `Promise.resolve` does is it takes an *expression* and turns it into a `Promise` that immediately resolves to that expression. If the expression is any type of plain value (primitive, array, object, etc) *other* than a `Promise`, then `Promise` returned by `Promise.resolve` will still resolve immediately. Your `getProductId` function is not returning anything, so your `prom2` results in a `Promise` that resolves immediately to the value of `undefined`.

`Promise.resolve` will not help your situation - you need to convert a callback to a `Promise`, and *the only way* to do that is to use the `new Promise` constructor:

```js
console.log('start');
const getProductId = () => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 1500, 5));
getProductId().then(res => console.log(res));
```

The time to use `Promise.resolve` is if you already have a value (synchronously) and want to turn it into a `Promise` that you can call `.then` on. For example, by using `Promise.resolve('begin')` as the initial value for the accumulator in the following code, a simple `Promise` chain can be constructed with `reduce`:

```js
const prom = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
  .reduce((lastProm, str) => (
    lastProm.then((lastStr) => {
      console.log(lastStr);
      return str;
    })),
    Promise.resolve('begin')
  );
  
prom.then((lastStr) => {
  console.log(lastStr);
  console.log('end');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

> ### [Promise.resolve()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)
>
> The **`Promise.resolve(value)`** method returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) object that is resolved with the given value. If the value is a promise, that promise is returned; if the value is a thenable (i.e. has a ["then" method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)), the returned promise will "follow" that thenable, adopting its eventual state; otherwise the returned promise will be fulfilled with the value. This function flattens nested layers of promise-like objects (e.g. a promise that resolves to a promise that resolves to something) into a single layer.

*So, basically the function `Promise.resolve` is returning the result of `getProductId` which is `undefined`.  If you want to get as result 5, you need to use `new Promise` constructor.*

This code snippet shows the result (55) of `getProductId` to demonstrate the usage of `Promise.resolve`.

```js
var getProductId = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    return 5;
  }, 1500);
  
  return 55
};
var prom2 = Promise.resolve(getProductId());

prom2.then(function(result) {
  console.log("55 = " + result);
});
```